# How to display teasers (fields), dependent of conditions user put into webform in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to make site that displays form, and makes user capable to input certain parameters in it. For example, real estate site. Let say I have these fields among others: location, price, size. If user choose to see houses under 100 000$, Drupal has to back node teasers (fields) for houses only under that price.

Now, I wonder how to make Views module start searching when user click submit button, and how to make conditions under which Views search, dynamically dependent of parameters users put into form.

Do I need some additional modules beside Views and Webform modules? Or maybe, I don't need them? Maybe I have to write some php/mysql script that do searching and fetching, but, naturally, I think Views module is build for that kind of circumstances. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There is an option in Views when you create the exposed filters: "**Remember the last selection**". This caches the user selection for each Views and when user visits the Views again he will see the previous filters enabled.

2) For better UX you can use [Better_Exposed_Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) and [Views_Saved_Searches](http://drupal.org/project/views_savedsearches) modules. With the first one you have much more options for exposed filters (eg expose as checkboxes) and with the last one users can **save their searches** and use them later (like bookmarking a url path).

PS. I don't think using the Webform module with views will be useful in order to create personal saved searches. Instead, Views Saved Searches is what you are looking for.